# A question about the nature of time travel in the movie Primer

Tags: primer

Thankfully my double hasn't shown up to stop me from embarrassing myself so here goes.

On quite a few sites describing the nature of time travel in Primer, including at least one that describes itself as the only definitive source, they say that the Aaron who left the US is fabricating an industrial sized box in order to create the ultimate failsafe, that is, it will allow him to go back farther and correct all of his past mistakes.

They also describe the act of "aging" boxes when they are used like Russian nesting dolls.

My confusion comes from the fact that I understood one of the unbreakable rules of the Primer universe to be that you can only go back as far as you activated the box initially.  Even if you bring another box, or boxes, in with you there is no way to "age" them more and push them farther back in time, rather they are used in order to create sub loops with more potential to perfect your plans to influence the present.

I was just wondering if I am misunderstanding something fundamental here or that the sites I am reading are incorrect.  There is also the possibility that I am misunderstanding the sites themselves.

Comment: You can carry a box into a box to create a nested loop. You can't take any object (including an activated box) any earlier than the activation date of the master box

Comment: Duplicate of [Why are the boxes in "Primer" recyclable?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/49745/why-are-the-boxes-in-primer-recyclable).

Comment: Can you link to the site you're thinking of? Did they actually use the phrase "go back farther" (or something equivalent) in comparison to the date they made the first human-sized box we saw in the movie?

Comment: Sorry for some reason I didn't receive the reply notifications, here is a link to the site that seemed to say that - http://theprimeruniverse.blogspot.com/2009/05/end.html - the exact quote is the entirety of the last paragraph.